# Optimization Calculus Question

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the maximum point on the graph
$$y = x^a(1-x)^b$$ 
where $a > b$ and the interval of $x$ is $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, nope I haven't tried it before.

Comment: I think they meant "what have you tried to solve the problem?". Show some effort.

Comment: Okay well I don't know how to go about this, I tried finding the derivative, but

Comment: Try using the product rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y=(x^a)(1-x)^b$, then $y'=ax^{a-1}(1-x)^b - bx^a(1-x)^{b-1}$.

To find the critical points, we set $y'=0$.

$$y'=ax^{a-1}(1-x)^b - bx^a(1-x)^{b-1}$$
$$=x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}(a-(a+b)x)=0$$

which yields the solutions $x=0,x=1,x=\frac{a}{a+b}$. Since $0 < x < 1$, the only critical point we need to consider is $\frac{a}{a+b}$. This gives the maximum point in the given interval (why?).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should have said $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ because the function has no maximum value in the interval if either is negative.

That being said, 
$$ x(1-x) \frac{d}{dx} x^a (1-x^b) = a(1-x) - bx$$Setting that to zero gives 
$$
x = \frac{a}{a+b}$$
and then $y$ can be read off.